# Back to the class in main.dart from another file

Tags: flutter, dart

I have two files. 
`main.dart`
`arview.dart`

in `arview.dart` there is callback fired by user motion, and I want to go back to the `main.dart` class from inside the callback

in `arview.dart`

```
class ArViewState extends State<ArViewWidget> with WidgetsBindingObserver {
.
.
.
    Future<void> onArchitectWidgetCreated() async {
        this.architectWidget.setJSONObjectReceivedCallback((jsonObjectReceived) {
        // I want to go back to the TopPage class in main.dart here.
        // however how can I do that?? my code is like this below.

            return Navigator.pushReplacement(context,
            NoAnimationMaterialPageRoute(
                builder: (context) => TopPage()));
```

in `main.dart`

```
import arview.dart;

class TopPage extends StatefulWidget {
  TopPage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);
  final String title;
  @override
  _TopPageState createState() => _TopPageState();
}

class _TopPageState extends State<TopPage> {
  Widget aboutButton(num){
    return Expanded(
      child:FlatButton(
        padding:EdgeInsets.only(bottom:10,right:5,left:5,top:10),
        child:  Image.asset("mybtn.png");
      ),
    );
  }
```

Comment: Are you sure that navigation line getting called. Please put a breakpoint in there and test it. You might also want to try something like Navigator.pop()

Comment: I use Navigator.push() and Navigator.pop(), it solved. I normally use pushReplacement, so miss it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Navigator.pop()` to go back.

> To implement a return to the original route, update the onPressed()
>   callback in the SecondRoute widget:

```
onPressed: () {
  Navigator.pop(context);
}
```